# Visual Basic find and replace any " not followed or proceeded by a comma with ""

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I want to write a vb or bat script that goes through a file and finds and replaces any quotation mark not followed or proceeded by a comma with a double quote.

**Edit: solved**

Ok so I got it I needed to use back references.

Incase anyone else needs something similar here is a little example script replacing " not followed or proceed by a comma with Doubleqoute

```
dim rp, file
set re = new RegExp

re.Pattern="([^,])("")([^,])"
re.Global=True
s="It is alive ""IT IS ALIVE"","

MsgBox re.Replace(s,"$1 DoubleQuote $3")
```

Comment: +1 for sharing the solution you found on your own.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it I needed to use back references.

Incase anyone else needs something similar here is a little example script replacing " not followed or proceed by a comma with Doubleqoute

```
dim rp, file
set re = new RegExp

re.Pattern="([^,])("")([^,])"
re.Global=True
s="It is alive ""IT IS ALIVE"","

MsgBox re.Replace(s,"$1 DoubleQuote $3")
```

EDIT: Also the above does not work with one letter words in order to make it work with one letter you have to use look forward and look back functions.